# Heroku Friendly Ruby Scraper (with AJAX)?

Tags: ruby, heroku, screen-scraping

So I'm trying to write a small unofficial API in Ruby to pull data from a site.  I like Mechanize, but all the data I need from the page is generated by AJAX so Mechanize doesn't see it at all.  What can I use to render a page with JavaScript so that I can scrape the data?  I think something like [spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner) but for Ruby would do the trick.

I would also like to play with Heroku, so I'm looking for something that could be deployed there, which leads me away from something like [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Does anything like this exist?

**Update**

For clarity, I'm trying to pull workout data from a [Fitocracy profile page](http://www.fitocracy.com/profile/DorkRawk/).

You may need an account before you can view the page, but basically all the workout data is displayed via JavaScript inside a page shell.

Comment: Hmm, I can't view that page, but there are many similar ajax questions here tagged screen-scraping. One of those will help you find the answer.

Comment: @pguardiario After playing with Chrome's Developer Tools for a bit I found the call that gave me exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ajax request is the same as a non-ajax request, it's just not always obvious how to make it. Mechanize can make any request that a browser can make. Sure Watir is easier but if this is for an API you should do it the right way and use mechanize.

Comment: But when I do an agent.get("http://page_im_trying_to_get_data_from"), none of the data is available because Mechanize hasn't rendered the JavaScript that produces that page content.  How can I get around this?

Comment: That's because the data is loaded in a second (ajax) request. If you need help making the second request I recommend that you post a new question and include the url.

Comment: Ok, I've added a link to the page I'm trying to scrape.  I don't think this needs to be a new question as the scraping of JS generated content with Mechanize seems pretty general.